# Create subsection in enumerate environment

Tags: sectioning

Currently I am using enumerate to create numbering. I want to include subsection within the enumerate environment with the numbers continue as they are. Well, some suggest me to use new enumerate but I want to remain the numbering. 
The subsection aligns with the content in the enumerate environment, which is not what I want. I want the subsection appears like normal (not the one shows in the code).

```
\begin{document}

      \begin{enumerate}

       \subsection*{blah blah blah}

      \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

I want to create subsection looks like this.

```
  \begin{document}

  \subsection*{blah blah blah}

  \end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand this question. Do you want numbered `\subsection`? Then use `\subsection` and not `\subsection*`

Comment: My question is: How to align subsections in enumerate environment with subsections which are not in enumerate environment?

Comment: And why do you use subsections within `enumerate` environment? I am quite curious about this

Comment: Actually I am compiling a stack of questions which are from different sections. But I want the numbering continues even though the questions are from different sections. For example, Q1-10 are from section A. Then Q11-20 are from section B. In between Q10 and Q11, I have to include a section to differentiate them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `resume` option of the `enumitem` package. You also have the concept of a `series` of enumerate environment, that share a common formatting.

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\setcounter{section}{1}

\begin{enumerate}
    \item First item.
    \item Second item
    \item A third item
 \end{enumerate}

\subsection{A subsection}

\begin{enumerate}[resume]
    \item Fourth item.
    \item Fifth item
 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]